# Host Visual C++ 2005 library DLLs in 4.0 application for SqlCompact

Tags: .net, visual-c++, sql-server-ce, visual-c++-2005, visual-c++-runtime

I have WPF Application Developed on MS VS2010 which connects on his own local DB (SqlCompact3.5) and Sql compact Dlls are very managed internally in solution.. 
The Issues starts when the application starts to crash on XP 32 Bit machine with only Framework 4.0 installed and after googling the exception logged on windows event viewer, I discovered a solution to install microsoft visual c++ 2005 redistributable sp1 Package and it works GREAT..

But I really need to have these DLLS internally in my application to avoid forcing all my customers to install extra package on their machines.. How can i do that !?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to use SQL Server Compact 4.0, as the private install of this includes the C++ libraries. I am not aware of any way to do the same with 3.5. See my blog for a detailed walkthrough.